# Threads with PhantomJS stay in task manager even after disposing

Tags: .net, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs, bots

I have a multithreading app that spawns threads that launch PhantomJS webdrivers. In the program I have an option that quits (disposes) all open webdrivers.

I use that option and they all close eventually. The problem is that it takes several seconds for all the webdriver instances to disapear from task manager even though all drivers are disposed. It can even take up to a minute depending on how many threads I have started. Is there a way to eliminate the instance from system tray also at the same time the webdriver is disposed?

Comment: The same for me. Do you subscribe for   `process.OutputDataReceived` and `process.ErrorDataReceived`?

Comment: No I didn't subscribe; I got rid of all the background workers and used threads all the way; I then scanned the system tray and killed them and they instantly got away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All those threads were started by a BackgroundWorker. I used another thread instead and the problem got away. You can then scan for the PhantomJS instances inside the System Tray and kill them without any errors appearing like they used to with the BackgroundWorker spawning them.